# Why the % variable is not working as ! variable in my batch file?

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I am using array in my for loop and trying to assign the value to a variable when each time loop process the array value. but when I am assigning the value to my variable, then the result is not as expected.

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
     @echo off
     setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
     SET var[0]=a
     SET var[1]=b
     SET var[2]=c
     SET var[3]=d
     for %%a in (0,1,2,3) do (
     SET name=%var[%%a]%
     ECHO %name%
     )
```

but the result is showing the last value of array which is 'd'. I don't want to use `ECHO !name!`. And expecting the output as below with `%`

```
 a
 b
 c
 d
```

Comment: Not sure of the reason why you do not want to use `delayedexpansion` but if you really refuse to use it, then disable delayedexpansion and then use `call echo %%name%%` which is ugly and has its own drawbacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally it would shown `ECHO is off.` because `%name%` wasn't declared before. Let's say that you set the default value to `null` for `%name%`, then the output would be `null` instead of `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`. That's because `%name%` was declared outside the loop.

What is going on here? The `echo %name%` inside the code block will get the variable `%name%` first before run it, and therefore your code inside code block after parsed would be:

```
(
  set name=
  rem "%var[%" = "" and "%a]%" also = ""
  echo 
  rem %name% wasn't here, because it's parsed before you run it.
)
```

The `!` symbol is the alternative variable pre/suffix, and only works if you use

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
```

Variable that's use `!` will only get parsed when the statement is actually running instead of parsing:

```
(
  set name=!var[%%a]!
  echo !name!
)
```

This time, the code block would ignore the `!` symbol and only looking for `%` symbol, and because the `for` loop, `%%a` will replace by a number:

```
(
  set name=!var[0]!
  echo !name!
)
(
  set name=!var[1]!
  echo !name!
)
(
  set name=!var[2]!
  echo !name!
)
(
  set name=!var[3]!
  echo !name!
)
```

Next time, if you want to change variable and use it, you might have to use `!` instead of `%` otherwise you'll get repeated result. And if you want to `echo` the `!` symbol, you can just escape it:

```
echo escaped "^!" symbol^!
```

Comment: Good explanation, but there is a tiny flaw in the last line `echo escaped "^!" symbol^!`, it only shows the first exclamation mark, you need to use double carets `echo escaped "^!" symbol^^!`